# unable to send out voice broadcast with callfire REST API

Tags: php, curl, callfire

I'm trying to send out an outbound call with the callfire REST API and am having some difficulty doing so. Here's my code (adapted from https://developers.callfire.com/docs.html#createVoiceBroadcast):

```
<?php
$username = '...';
$password = '...';

$data = array(
    'name' => 'Automation Test',
    'fromNumber' => '...',
    'recipients' => array(
        array('phoneNumber' => '...')
    ),
    'answeringMachineConfig' => 'AM_AND_ALIVE',
    'liveSoundText' => 'hello, world!',
    'machineSoundText' => 'hello, world!'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://api.callfire.com/v2/campaigns/voice-broadcasts');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

print_r($result);
```

The problem is in the response. It's as follows:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [httpStatusCode] => 415
    [internalCode] => 0
    [message] => Exception in API
)
```

The 415 status code is for "Unsupported Media Type" per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error but since I'm not uploading any media that error doesn't really make a lot of sense.

Maybe my value for `answeringMachineConfig` is invalid. idk what AM_AND_LIVE is supposed to mean but it's in the example so I'm using it. If there's only a small number of possible values the documentation should say so..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set content type to 'application/json'.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10711874)

Comment: @mjp66 - I actually think it might. But I won't be able to test it out until Wednesday morning..

Answer (score 1):

Old I know, but just ran across it. Perhaps:

```
'answeringMachineConfig' => 'AM_AND_ALIVE',
```

should be:

```
'answeringMachineConfig' => 'AM_AND_LIVE',
```

You wrote ALIVE instead of LIVE